# Sorting API results at a higher object level

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, sorting, object

I'm using the NY state legislature API and creating a feed of bill actions in chronological order. Currently, I'm getting results like:

- Bill A123, 2021-04/19, Moved to Committee
- Bill A123, 2021-04/12, Introduced
- Bill S888, 2021-04/17, Signed into law
- Bill S888, 2021-04/01, Passed Senate

So essentially, it's correctly sorting but only WITHIN a single bill. INSTEAD, what I'd want for this data is for it to sort entirely on date, ACROSS bills, for example with the same data as above:

- Bill A123, 2021-04/19, Moved to Committee
- Bill S888, 2021-04/17, Signed into law
- Bill A123, 2021-04/12, Introduced
- Bill S888, 2021-04/01, Passed Senate

The way this is set up in the API is that you have a bill object, with a bill number (e.g. A123), and that bill has an object has anywhere from zero to dozens of "actions." Each individual action, when they exist, have a date and text describing it.

So with that all said, here's my code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  const apiUrl = "https://legislation.nysenate.gov/api/3/bills/2021/";
  const bills = ["A2260", "S737", "A559", "S775", "S737", "A3041", "S3121", "S1234" ];
  const requests = bills.map(bill => {
    return $.getJSON(apiUrl + bill + "?key=[insertkeyhere]")
  });

  Promise.all(requests).then(results => {

    // try the sort and append for the feed
    for (let { result } of results) {
      const sortedItems = result.actions.items.sort(function (itemA, itemB) {
        return itemA.date - itemB.date;
      }).reverse();
      
      for (let { printNo, date, text } of sortedItems) {
        // if (date > "2021-03-10") {
          const $p = $('<p>').append( "On " + date + ", <a href='https://www.nysenate.gov/legislation/bills/2021/" + result.printNo + "'>" + result.printNo + "</a> was " + text );
          $('#bill-feed').append($p);
        // }
      }
    }

    // show full list of bill info
    var counter = 0;
    for (let {printNo, title} of results) {
      const $p = $('<p>').append("<a href='https://www.nysenate.gov/legislation/bills/2021/" + bills[counter] + "'>" + results[counter].result.printNo + '</a>. ' + results[counter].result.title);
      $('#bill-list').append($p);
      counter++;
    }


  }).catch(err => console.log('Oooops, one of the requests failed'));
});

</script>

</head>
<body>

<h2>Actions Feed</h2>
<div id="bill-feed"></div>

<hr />
<h2>List of Bills</h2>
<div id="bill-list"></div>
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Any chance you can include the API response so we can see what you are working with?

Comment: Do you mean something like this? https://imgur.com/a/nb0JWS9

Comment: Yes but actually display the full object on here.  It looks like you want multiple date values to be sorted, correct?  You not only want the individual bills sorted by date, but also the objects in which the bills are nested in?  Does this sound right?  If so, seeing the whole object would help a lot.

Comment: So I only want the "actions" to be sorted, regardless of the bill that they represent. The only two objects are "bills" and "actions" (which are a child of bills). There's nothing above "bills." Sorry for confusion. What I'm trying to describe is sorting actions across different bills.